# C Signal usage and process using IPC message queues

Tags: c, signals

I have a program that uses a signal (SIGUSR2) for setup a catch handler function to process high priority incoming messages.

The program receives incoming messages off an IPC message queue using msgrcv() in its main loop.  When the sender of messages to the IPC message queue wants to notify the program that a high priority one is incoming, it sends SIGUSR2 to the process to have it stop processing any current message that may be being processed.

In the signal catch handler function I first upon entry do:

signal(SIGUSR2, SIG_IGN);

to ignore any new signals for preemption to occur.

then the code processes the preemption request where it stores the currently being processed message back into the queue, housekeeping, etc.  and then just before returning from the signal handler function it does:

signal(SIGUSR2, sighandler_func);

Question:  If another flash processing signal is received just a nanosecond after
           the above signal call is issued, will the process re-dispatch to the
           signal handler function again?  ie: if the code in the main loop where
           it does the sighold(SIGUSR2) and sigrelse(SIGUSR2) to stop / start the
           receipt of the preemption signal take precedence or is it just the 
           above signal call that re-energizes the signal handler?

Comment: My [Magic 8 Ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_8-Ball) says "Reply Hazy, Try Again".  Please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - preferably with actual code.

Comment: Seems much easier andessential racy to simply use a second queue for high-priority messages.

Comment: agreed, but I'm limited by the client in the scope of changes that I can make.

Comment: Also, SysV IPC message queues already support prioritizing messages.  Why not just have a thread blocking on high-priority messages, and let another thread handle lower-priority ones?  I strongly suspect your signal-handling code is way too complex and likely calls non-async-signal-safe functions - note that `msgrcv()` and other SysV IPC functions are not async-signal-safe and should never be called from a signal handler.

Comment: The signal receipt of the flash preemption is ONLY enable during message sending (basically write system calls) - not during the IPC msgrcv calls.

Answer (score 2):

You should use sigaction for that:

```
struct sigaction act;
memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act);
act.sa_handler = sighandler_func;
sigaction(SIGUSR2, &act, NULL);
```

This way, the signal handler is automatically called with the signal blocked, which caused the event (in your case SIGUSR2). If now a `SIGUSR2` arrives during the execution of the handler, it is blocked until the signal handler returns. Then, (when the signal is unblocked), the signal handler is called immediately again.

However, you will have to handle the case, that multiple `SIGUSR2` arrive during one execution of the signal handler properly, since it will be called only *once* after return of the handler then.

Comment: yes, in an upcoming version the signal handling calls are all made using POSIX compliant calls using sigaction.